# Detectability of packing files in Windows 10

Tags: compression

I follow the tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g0RmclTe7Lo

to pack calc.exe in windows 10 at

> C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe

But I get the following error: 
[image]

What's the problem?

It seems windows 10 is able to detect the packed internal libraries like calc.exe and cmd.exe and prevent it from being executed. How this is possible? When I use UPX to pack other binaries (windows binaries, but not windows internal binaries), this is not happening.

Comment: they are in System32 and signed - you broke the signing

Comment: @schroeder Thanks, when I take calc.exe and cmd.exe out of System32, like place them in Desktop, they are running too..is there a specific URLs that talked about this process?